# Deleting matching pattern with sed doesn't work with mac os Catalina

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm desperately looking for an answer to an apparently very simple problem: I want to delete all matching pattern from a txt file.
I'm using the following command under Mac OS Catalina:

```
sed 's/^M//' $filename > text_clean.txt
```

Where `$filename` contains the name of the txt file I'm performing the operation in.
The "^M" pattern stands for the new line character under Mac OS : I've tested almost everything from what I could find, and this is the only solution working.

So, what is happening is that the following command does the job:

```
sed 's/^M/AAAAA/' $filename > text_clean.txt
```

But only partly because it's replacing with the "AAAAA" characters, which is not what I want.

When executing sed 's/^M//' $filename > text_clean.txt, the resulting file is completely unchanged, so I'm guessing that either the command is not executed (but why?), or I must insert a specific "empty" character since I'm using the Mac OS shell (but which one?).

I've also tested with gsed (after having installed homebrew) ... but the results are strictly the same as above.

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I really don't see what !

Comment: `sed 's/\r//g' $filename > text_clean.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C escapes in sed are a GNU extension that will work with the aforementioned `gsed` (assuming that stands for GNU sed).

Comment: Then how about `sed 's/'$'\r''//g' "$filename" > text_clean.txt`

Comment: `:)` Perhaps `sed` isn't *notarized* to run on Catalina and Gatekeeper is preventing it from running `:)`  See e.g. [Not LibreOffice too? Beloved open-source suite latest to fall victim to the curse of Catalina](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/23/libreoffice_latest_victim_of_curse_of_catalina/)

Comment: Use `tr` like this `tr -d '\r' <inputfile >outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

Lets try with another way using grep.

I have created a test.txt file as below

```
bash-3.2$ cat test.txt
AA
BB
CC
MA
MB
BM
CM
MU
MZ
SH
JH
HJ
12M
M45
M*&
M#$
12
```

with grep

```
bash-3.2$ grep -v ^M test.txt > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt test.txt
```

do a grep with "^M", ie all lines starting with "M" and choosing the rest of the lines using the inverse option "-v". Moving the output of grep into a tmp.txt file and then replacing this file as the original file.

```
bash-3.2$ cat test.txt
AA
BB
CC
BM
CM
SH
JH
HJ
12M
12
```

Goodluck.